# Should I subclass or use a category

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have a singleton that manages preferences which are loaded from a plist. I use it multiple apps.  It contains methods like `-(BOOL)boolForKey:(NSString *)key defaultValue:(BOOL)def`

So I can get use the class in two different apps, just by supplying different keys, such as in one app: `[PreferenceManager boolForKey:@"UseAlternateColors" defaultValue:NO];`

But it would be easier to have a method like `-(BOOL)useAlternateColors` (which just returns the value from the above line) just in that app. So should I add this method to `PreferenceManager` using a category (and only have the category in the one app) or create subclass like `OneAppPreferenceManager`?

In this specific example, is it better to subclass or use a category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclassing would have been a better option if you needed to add new data members to the derived `PreferenceManager`. However, since the backing storage always remains the same, I think that using a category would be preferable in this specific case.

Using a category would let your keep the singleton `PreferenceManager` unchanged, along with the piece of code that sets it up. If you were to subclass `PreferenceManager`, you would need to make an additional change to the code that instantiates the singleton, so that it uses the `PreferenceManagerSubclass` instead of the raw `PreferenceManager`. With a category, this change would be unnecessary.